# how to use #include for GSL library in VS2022

Tags: c++, c++20, visual-studio-2022, gsl

how do I get VS2022 using C++20 to recognize the location of the GSL library ?

this line is working:
#include"C:\Users\examples\libraries\GSL\include\gsl\algorithm"

---

but if I use this format instead:
#include <gsl/algorithm>

in the Project Properties Page, Configuration Properties> C/C++> General:
Additional Include Directories (is set to ) C:\Users\examples\libraries\GSL\include\gsl\

but that causes the following error.
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "gsl/algorithm"
C:\Users\examples\libraries\GSL\include\gsl

Am I putting the location of the 'algorithm' file in the wrong place in Project Properties Page ???

I do not know how to use the CMakeSettings.json or if there is a formal way to install this gsl folder ???
I am new to both VS2022 & C++20 and just copied the 'gsl' folder from an online source.

Comment: Thank you Ken for the correct answer as I had not been  able to fix it all weekend. I had tried putting that folder in a dozen places. VS2022 has many settings on the project Properties Page that deal with directories and paths which I also tried.

Comment: How do I credit you for the correct answer ?

Comment: Let me do an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix, you should not be using the `gsl` portion in the `Project Properties Page, Configuration Properties> C/C++> General: Additional Include Directories` page. So:

```
C:\Users\examples\libraries\GSL\include\gsl
```

should be:

```
C:\Users\examples\libraries\GSL\include
```

This is so when you add the path plus the include file you end up with `C:\Users\examples\libraries\GSL\include\gsl\algorithm` instead of `C:\Users\examples\libraries\GSL\include\gsl\gsl\algorithm`.

PS: I prefer using forward slashes for directories even on Windows as it avoids the extra mental overhead of remembering that they are not escape characters.

Comment: thanks Ken, I really got lost with all the incorrect possibilities of where to put the literal directory path in the settings pages; such as VC++, C/C++ etc. Your NOT example of 'gsl/gsl' really made it crystal clear why it didn't work. The 'examples' folder has lots of sub, sub, sub folders which have 'gsl' folders in some of them. I just grabbed the 1st one that had the files that the compiler wanted. One of the deeper folders has a "CMakeSettings.json" file. Is this file used to install the 'gsl' library ? There are other '.json' files in other subfolders. I have never knowingly used these.

Comment: l wanted to edit my last comment but seems like I can not. Anyway, the '.json' files seem to be for distributing a project not for installing libraries; with that in mind, is there an 'installer' type of file I should be using ???